# Why we have $| \mathcal{F}(X\times Y, Z)|=| \mathcal{F}(Y, \mathcal{F}(X, Z))|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let

1. $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are finite sets.
2. $\mathcal{F}(X, Y)$ is the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$
3. $| X |$ is number of members in $X$ and
4. $X\times Y$ is the product of $X$ and $Y$.

Now, Why we have
\begin{align*}
| \mathcal{F}(X\times Y, Z)|=| \mathcal{F}(Y, \mathcal{F}(X, Z))|.
\end{align*}

Thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointing out an explicit bijection should be the preffered way, if possible and easy. So we want:

$$F:\mathcal{F}(X\times Y, Z)\to\mathcal{F}(X,\mathcal{F}(Y,Z))$$

which we will now define. Since $F(f)$ is supposed to be an element of $\mathcal{F}(X, \mathcal{F}(Y,Z))$ then we can evaluate it on $x\in X$, getting $F(f)(x)$ which now is supposed to be an element of $\mathcal{F}(Y,Z)$ and so we can evaluate it on $y\in Y$ which gives us the nested definition, the only reasonable:

$$F(f)(x)(y):=f(x,y)$$

This makes sense since $f\in\mathcal{F}(X\times Y, Z)$. Analogously define

$$G:\mathcal{F}(X,\mathcal{F}(Y,Z))\to \mathcal{F}(X\times Y, Z)$$
$$G(f)(x,y):=f(x)(y)$$

Can you prove that these are inverses of each other and hence bijections?

Note that the assumption about $X,Y,Z$ being finite is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just use that $\mid A^B\mid=\mid A\mid^{\mid B\mid}$ and $\mid A×B\mid=\mid A\mid\mid B\mid$.

So $\mid Z^{X×Y}\mid=\mid Z\mid^{\mid X×Y\mid}=\mid Z\mid ^{\mid X\mid\mid Y\mid}$.

And, $\mid (Z^X)^Y\mid=\mid Z^X\mid^{\mid Y\mid}=({\mid Z\mid^{\mid X\mid}})^{\mid Y\mid}=\mid Z\mid^{\mid X\mid\mid Y\mid}$.

I prefer the notation $Y^X$ for $\mathcal F(X,Y)$.

Comment: Why would $(|Z|^{|X|})^{|Y|} = |Z|^{|X| |Y|}$? I mean, of course this is true, but it is exactly what the question asks to show.

Comment: That $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ is an easy fact from elementary algebra.  @MarkKamsma

Comment: Although the OP mentions finite sets, finiteness is unnecessary here. Of course what the question should ask is to prove that the two sides are naturally isomorphic functors of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ $\ddot\smile$. @ChrisCuster

Comment: @Chris Ah yes, I was thinking infinite cardinalities.